# How to assign a static IP address to different devices

Tags: router, ip, lan

I want to configure the router to assign the same IP address 192.168.1.101 for different devices. Only one device will be connected to router at a time.

The purpose I want to do so is because I am running a test and want to ping the same address every time I connect a different device.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to superuser! Could you provide more information, like the model of router you have.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Details depend on your router, and what DHCP software it is using. Many routers use `dnsmasq`, google for the configuration file documentation.

Comment: Check your router's DHCP configuration capabilities for assigning ***reserved*** IP addresses using MAC addresses.  See https://kb.netgear.com/25722/How-do-I-reserve-an-IP-address-on-my-NETGEAR-router

Comment: @sawdust I don't want to reserved different IP address for different MAC address. I want to assign one IP address only for different MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a DHCP pool of one, 192.168.1.101 as lower and upper limit will do what you want. Exact steps depend on your router model which you have not provided.

Comment: I am using Linksys WRT160NL Wireless-N router. I tried to set the maximum number of users = (1), start IP Address = 192.168.1.101 and Subnet Mask = 255.255.255.0. After that, my device can't get any IP address.

Comment: Looking at page 7 of this PDF http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/1224641340473/WRT160NL_V10_UG_NC-WEB.pdf, you set the start IP address, set user =1 and client lease time 5 minutes (so the client requests renewal every 5 minutes) this should work, maybe bug (off by one) try 2 users. What does IP Address Range read ?

Answer (score 0):

On the router's WebAdmin Static IP page, add the IP address you want static, then in it's MAC address section, add the MAC addresses of every device you want the IP address to apply to *(the format will likely be a whitespace between each MAC address)*.

- If the WebAdmin does not allow this, and there is no area to add custom config parameters to `dnsmasq`'s *(or whatever DHCP server the router is running)*, look into opensource firmware, such as [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt160n)

  - **OpenWrt is recommended** anyway since this router reached EOL [End of Life] in 2013 and has not had a security patch or update since 2019.09.05.  Due to this router having only [4MB](https://openwrt.org/supported_devices/openwrt_on_432_devices) of storage for firmware, configuring it with [extroot](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/extroot_configuration) on a USB drive will be required.